# Redux Toolkit, Testing createAsyncThunk actions with it's cycles

Tags: redux, jestjs, redux-toolkit, react-native-testing-library

I am trying to test `createAsyncThunk` actions the same way I test `createAction` but it fails and nothing changes in the reducers.

I have made a small app to simulate the cases I made createAsyncThunk and made some tests for it but unfortunately, any tests related to `createAsyncThunk` fail.

here's the Repo link [ReduxToolkitTesting](https://github.com/MuhmdRaouf/ReduxToolkitTesting)

Lib used this is Repo

- Redux Toolkit (For Sure :D)
- React-navigation (Assuming this is the most used navigation lib)
- UI Kitten (Theming and Components ready to use)

Store consists of 2 reducers

- Gallery:

  - Set loading indicator to true till fetch is done
  - Fetch random pic from public API and set loading indicator to false
  - If an error happened it reject with an error message and set loading indicator to false
  - Reset Picture to default state
- Theme

  - Toggle to switch between dark or light theme (also `createAsyncThunk` cuz I need access to getState), I know I can just pass the value but I need it to be like this just for testing experiment.

I made tests for both reducers and for the Home page which contain buttons to simulate all these behaviors too,

also made render function as mentioned in [Redux Doc](https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-tests#components)
but and just add the store in the return from the render function with `Jest.spyOn` on all the functions in case of want to check specific action calls.

right now any test related to `createAsyncThunk` is failing and can't find any way to fix it or to test some functionalities in another way.

**PS. This is might be a lot to ask but I won't remove this Repo and it would be huge if we could contribute to it to be something like a live example on how to test Redux Toolkit and add more scenarios with its a test for advanced testing would be awesome too.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to explain your question instead of a whole project link?

Comment: @slideshowp2 Actually this project is the example, I made to demonstrate the problem I am facing.